# Sudoku Solver for Multiple Solutions - Missing Solutions

Tags: c++, recursion, sudoku, backtracking

I have most of the program done but when I try it with a partially filled sudoku that is supposed to have 8 solutions, it prints out one less solution that it is supposed to. Here is my function for finding all the alternatives:

```
void guess(Puzzle *puzzle, list<Puzzle> *solutions, stack<Puzzle> *alternatives)
{    
    int i, j, x;

    while(!(*puzzle).isSolved(i, j))
    {
        for(x = 1; x <= 9; ++x)
        {
            if((*puzzle).checkCell(i, j, x))
            {
                (*puzzle).assign(i, j, x);

                Puzzle alternative;
                alternative.initialize(&(*puzzle));

                if(solve(&alternative1))
                {
                    (*solutions).push_back(alternative);
                    (*alternatives).push(*puzzle);
                } // if
            } // if
        } // for

        (*puzzle).initialize(&(*alternatives).top());
        (*alternatives).pop();
    } // while
} // guess
```

The cells (i,j) are only checked if they are empty. The function isSolved() takes (i,j) and places the empty cell numbers i and j into (i,j) so that when the program guesses, it only guesses the empty cells.

Here is my function solve() that solves for one single solution for each given partially filled in puzzle that is passed in from guess():

```
bool solve(Puzzle *alternative)
{
    int i, j, x;

    if((*alternative).isSolved(i, j))
        return true;

    for(x = 1; x <= 9; ++x)
    {
        if((*alternative).checkCell(i, j, x))
        {
            (*alternative).assign(i, j, x);
            if(solve(alternative))
                return true;
            (*alternative).assign(i, j, 0);
        } // if
    } // for

    return false;
} // solve()
```

Here is the partially filled sudoku that I tried it with: 
.8...9743.5...8.1..1.......8....5......8.4......3....6.......7..3.5...8.9724...5.

My program works just fine with it is supplied with most puzzles, except when it is used to find multiple solutions, then it tends to miss one or 2 solutions. Please help!

Comment: What is `Puzzle::isSolved(int, int)`? `i` and `j` are not initialized before using them in the while statement.

Comment: @AviGinsburg: I guess `bool Puzzle::isSolved(int&, int&)`. (and affect `i, j` to the first empty cell coord).